# Rank data with history of recurrence

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Lets say I'm tracking a user's location, and I capture the following information:

1. Date
2. UserId
3. CurrentLocation

I can do a fairly easy transformation on this data to form a new table to get their last known position, if one exists, which I'll include below to show us moving from one point to another.

I want to create a grouping for each user's current position, and increment it whenever their position has changed from a previous value. If a user leaves a position, and later comes back to it, I want that to be treated as a new value, and not lump it in with the group when they were first at this location.

The problem with using RANK or DENSE_RANK to do this is that I'm ordering by the currentPos, which obviously won't work.

I thought I could use LAG() to look at the previous data, but this doesn't allow you to aggregate the previous record's LAG() with the current row.

Here's an example using RANK()

```
WITH dummyData(id, occuredOn, userId, currentPos, lastPos) AS (
    SELECT 01, '2021-01-01 00:00:00', 23, 'A', null
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 22, '2021-01-01 01:30:00', 23, 'A', 'A'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 43, '2021-01-01 04:00:00', 23, 'B', 'A'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 55, '2021-01-02 00:00:00', 23, 'C', 'B'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 59, '2021-01-02 04:40:00', 23, 'B', 'C'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 68, '2021-01-02 08:00:00', 23, 'C', 'B'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 69, '2021-01-02 09:00:00', 23, 'D', 'C'

    UNION ALL
    SELECT 11, '2021-01-01 01:00:00', 43, 'X', 'X'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 18, '2021-01-01 02:00:00', 43, 'Y', 'X'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 32, '2021-01-02 00:00:00', 43, 'Z', 'Y'
)
SELECT *
    , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY currentPos) locationChangeGroup
FROM dummyData
ORDER BY userId ASC, occuredOn ASC
```

Here's what it outputs

| id | occurredOn | userId | currentPos | lastPos | locationChangeGroup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 23 | A | NULL | 1 |
| 22 | 2021-01-01 01:30:00 | 23 | A | A | 1 |
| 43 | 2021-01-01 04:00:00 | 23 | B | A | 2 |
| 55 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | 23 | C | B | 3 |
| 59 | 2021-01-02 04:40:00 | 23 | B | C | 2 |
| 68 | 2021-01-02 08:00:00 | 23 | C | B | 3 |
| 69 | 2021-01-02 09:00:00 | 23 | D | C | 4 |
| 11 | 2021-01-01 01:00:00 | 43 | X | X | 1 |
| 18 | 2021-01-01 02:00:00 | 43 | Y | X | 2 |
| 32 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | 43 | Z | Y | 3 |

Here's what I want

| id | occurredOn | userId | currentPos | lastPos | locationChangeGroup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 23 | A | NULL | 1 |
| 22 | 2021-01-01 01:30:00 | 23 | A | A | 1 |
| 43 | 2021-01-01 04:00:00 | 23 | B | A | 2 |
| 55 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | 23 | C | B | 3 |
| 59 | 2021-01-02 04:40:00 | 23 | B | C | 4 |
| 68 | 2021-01-02 08:00:00 | 23 | C | B | 5 |
| 69 | 2021-01-02 09:00:00 | 23 | D | C | 6 |
| 11 | 2021-01-01 01:00:00 | 43 | X | X | 1 |
| 18 | 2021-01-01 02:00:00 | 43 | Y | X | 2 |
| 32 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | 43 | Z | Y | 3 |

I know I could do this with a CURSOR, but I'd rather not resort to that.

T-SQL is fine, but I'm trying to stay away from any stored procs or functions, as it will require a larger effort of generating database migration scripts and the rigamarole of our processes that entails.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a gap-and-islands problem.  For this purpose, you can use `lag()` and a cumulative sum:

```
select dd.*,
       sum(case when prev_currentpos = currentpos then 0 else 1 end) over
            (partition by userid
             order by occurredon
            ) as locationChangeGroup
from (select dd.*,
             lag(currentpos) over (partition by userid order by occurredon) as prev_currentpos
      from dummydata dd
     ) dd
```